# No Output in the log file generated by logback

Tags: windows, logging, tomcat6, logback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Setup Logback with Tomcat 6 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620848/how-to-setup-logback-with-tomcat-6-on-windows)

I have setup logback on my tomcat6 on Windows 7, copied [logback-access-0.9.13],[logback-classic-0.9.13],[logback-core-0.9.13] in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib and copied logback-access.xml in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf. The xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
     <append>true</append>
     <File>${catalina.home}/logs/aggregator.log</File>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] \(%class{25}:%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
       <fileNamePattern>aggregator.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
     </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
     <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] \(%class{25}:%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
 <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Also added the following line in server.xml:

```
<Valve className="ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve"/>
```

The problem is that the log file is created but nothing is logged in it. The tomcat setup is just basic, normal startup should be logged in the log file.

Can somebody help me, please?

P.S. I am using older version of logback as I have read somewhere the newer version will not work with tomcat6.

Thanks
Noman A.

Comment: Where in server.xml did you add the Valve exactly?

Comment: The value is added right under:  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">